# Outlook alias and System.Net.Mail

Tags: .net, outlook, outlook-2007

Is it possible to resolve a users Outlook Alias to a valid SMTP email address using System.Net.Mail?

I know it can be done with Outlook automation but I am trying not to use it as Outlook 2007 has spam filter protection that require user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in an Active Directory environment, you can use System.DirectoryServices with a correctly-crafted AD/LDAP query. I'm not sure what you consider an "Outlook Alias" to be, so I can't tell you what the exact query should be.